# How to append to the right ID's column in CSV with pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, random-forest

I have got a test file and 100 model which I would like to evaluate on the test.

In the test file there are 2 column, first is IDs and the second is Probability.

I would like that each model would append it's evaluation to a new column next to the relevant ID.

My code right now build it under each other, like this:

```
1 0.1
2 0.12
3 0.32
1 0.21
2 0.22
3 0.17
```

And I would need form like this:

```
1 0.1 0.21
2 0.12 0.22
3 0.32 0.17
```

to a csv.

My code looks like this:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('test_numeric_out.csv', chunksize=10000):
chunk = chunk.drop(chunk.columns[len(chunk.columns)-1], axis=1)
for model in models:
    X_test = chunk.drop(['Id'],axis=1)
    inputnames = X_test.columns.values
    X_test['p_0']=0
    X_test['p_1']=0
    X_test[ ['p_0','p_1'] ]  = model.predict_proba(X_test[inputnames])
    submission = pd.DataFrame({
        "Id":chunk['Id'],
        "Response":X_test['p_1']
        })
    if (head==0):
        submission.to_csv(proba_out_csv,
        index=False,
        header=True,
        mode='a',
        chunksize=100000)
    else:
        submission.to_csv(proba_out_csv,
        index=False,
        header=False,
        mode='a',
        chunksize=100000)
    head = 1
```

Comment: Please, fix an indentation: indent of all lines but first have to be increased.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can be done a bit easier.

```
inputnames = chunk.columns.drop('Id').values
# drop works here too, so no need to create additional dataframe
# to get inputnames
for i, model in enumerate(models):
    chunk['p_1_{}'.format(i)]  = model.predict_proba(chunk[inputnames])[:, 1]
    # we are interested only in the second column
    # do not need to create different dataframe to store results
    # just create distinct column for each model
chunk.to_csv(proba_out_csv)
```